# Dot-and-whiskers error when plotting multiple regressions in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression

I have followed the code on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843781/dot-and-whisker-plots-of-filtered-estimates-for-multiple-regression-models) to plot multiple regressions using dot-and-whiskers, but receive the following error when trying to replicate results and when running the code with my own data and models:

```
Error in match.arg(tolower(centrality), c("median", "mean", "map", "trimmed",  : 
  'arg' should be one of “median”, “mean”, “map”, “trimmed”, “all"
```

I am running the following code:

```
nblaborforcer <- glm.nb(asylum~laborforcerl + hr_scoreL + warL + asylumL + origin-1 + offset(log(population)), data = dissertation2, control = glm.control(maxit = 500))
nb1 <- tidy(nblaborforcer)
nblaborforcefpercent<- glm.nb(asylum~laborforcefpercentL + hr_scoreL + warL + asylumL + origin-1 + offset(log(population)), data = dissertation2, control = glm.control(maxit = 500))
nb2 <- tidy(nblaborforcefpercent)
dwplot(list(nb1, nb2))+ ylim(breaks = c("laborforcerl", "laborforcefpercentL"))
```

When I run the following code [found here](https://github.com/easystats/bayestestR/issues/408) to solve this problem:

```
dwplot(list(nb1, nb2), centrality = NULL)+ ylim(breaks = c("laborforcerl", "nblaborforcefpercent"))
```

I receive this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "estimate", value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 8
```

Here is my traceback

```
> traceback()
5: stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
       "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA)
4: `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "estimate", value = numeric(0))
3: `$<-`(`*tmp*`, "estimate", value = numeric(0))
2: add_NAs(df, n_models, mod_names)
1: dwplot(list(nb1, nb2), centrality = NULL)
```

Here is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] broom.mixed_0.2.7 glmmTMB_1.1.2.3   lme4_1.1-26       Matrix_1.3-4      broom_0.7.6      
 [6] dotwhisker_0.7.4  jtools_2.1.4      boot_1.3-28       pscl_1.5.5        MASS_7.3-54      
[11] plyr_1.8.6        forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.5       purrr_0.3.4      
[16] readr_1.4.0       tidyr_1.1.4       tibble_3.1.1      ggplot2_3.3.5     tidyverse_1.3.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.2          pkgload_1.1.0       jsonlite_1.7.2      splines_4.0.2      
 [5] modelr_0.1.8        datawizard_0.2.1    assertthat_0.2.1    statmod_1.4.35     
 [9] pander_0.6.4        ggstance_0.3.5      cellranger_1.1.0    bayestestR_0.11.0  
[13] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 pillar_1.6.0        backports_1.2.1     lattice_0.20-44    
[17] glue_1.4.2          digest_0.6.27       rvest_1.0.0         minqa_1.2.4        
[21] colorspace_2.0-0    pkgconfig_2.0.3     haven_2.4.1         scales_1.1.1       
[25] generics_0.1.0      farver_2.0.3        ellipsis_0.3.1      withr_2.3.0        
[29] TMB_1.7.22          cli_2.5.0           magrittr_2.0.1      crayon_1.4.1       
[33] readxl_1.3.1        fs_1.5.0            fansi_0.4.1         nlme_3.1-148       
[37] xml2_1.3.2          tools_4.0.2         hms_1.0.0           lifecycle_1.0.0    
[41] munsell_0.5.0       reprex_2.0.0        compiler_4.0.2      rlang_0.4.10       
[45] grid_4.0.2          nloptr_1.2.2.2      parameters_0.14.0   rstudioapi_0.13    
[49] labeling_0.4.2      testthat_3.0.0      gtable_0.3.0        DBI_1.1.1          
[53] R6_2.5.0            lubridate_1.7.10    utf8_1.1.4          rprojroot_2.0.2    
[57] insight_0.14.5      desc_1.2.0          stringi_1.5.3       Rcpp_1.0.5         
[61] vctrs_0.3.7         dbplyr_2.1.1        tidyselect_1.1.0
```

I would ideally like to have a plot with 5+ regressions.

**Update**

When I run the code with sample data mtcars, I get the desired result. When I use my data with negative binomial models, I get the same error.

```
options("install.lock"=FALSE)

install.packages("ggplot2")
library(dotwhisker)
library(dplyr)
install.packages("tidyr")
library(tidyverse)

data("mtcars")

m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + disp + gear, data = mtcars)
dwplot(m1) + ylim(c("wt"))
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . + hp) # add another predictor
m3 <- update(m2, . ~ . + am) # and another 

summary(m1)
summary(m2)

dwplot(list(m1, m2, m3)) + ylim(c("wt", "cyl"))

dissertation2<-read.csv("C:/Users/diron/Google Drive/Vanderbilt/R working directory/dissertation2.csv")

library(MASS)
install.packages("pscl")
library(pscl)
install.packages("boot")
library(boot)
install.packages("jtools")
library(jtools)

nblaborforcer <- glm.nb(asylum~laborforcerl + hr_scoreL + warL + asylumL + origin-1 + offset(log(population)), data = dissertation2, control = glm.control(maxit = 500))

nb1 <- tidy(nblaborforcer)
dwplot(nb1) + ylim(c("laborforcerl"))

nblaborforcefpercent<- glm.nb(asylum~laborforcefpercentL + hr_scoreL + warL + asylumL + origin-1 + offset(log(population)), data = dissertation2, control = glm.control(maxit = 500))
nb2<-tidy(nblaborforcefpercent)
dwplot(nb2) + ylim(c("laborforcefpercentL"))

dwplot(list(nb1,nb2))

Error in match.arg(tolower(centrality), c("median", "mean", "map", "trimmed",  : 
  'arg' should be one of “median”, “mean”, “map”, “trimmed”, “all”
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different package I have to use since I am using negative binomial models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question using `tidy models`, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843781/dot-and-whisker-plots-of-filtered-estimates-for-multiple-regression-models).

```
nb1 <- tidy(nblaborforcer)  %>% 
   mutate(model = "nb1")
nb2 <- tidy(nblaborforcefpercent)  %>% 
   mutate(model = "nb2")
tidy_mods <- bind_rows(nb1, nb2)
dwplot(tidy_mods) + ylim(c("laborforcerl", "laborforcefpercentL"))
```